# Django-rest-framework timezone aware renderers/parsers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building an app that would serve people located in different places arround the world.
I'm using Django-Rest-Framwork for the communication between the clients and the server.
All DateTime values are saved to the DB as UTC (I have `USE_TZ = True` and `TIME_ZONE = 'Greenwich'` in settings.py).

I will be getting from the user his/her local timezone.

To **test** DRF for timezone awareness I wrote this middleware with fixed timezone:

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        timezone.activate(pytz.timezone("Asia/Jerusalem"))
```

The problem is:
I have a case in which I'm getting from the user "start_time" and "end_time" fields containting datetimes in the user's **LOCAL** timezone which gets through the `UnicodeJSONRenderer` to a `ModelSerializer` and then saved to the DB. However, they are saved **as if they were in UTC**.

At this point I would expect the serializer (or parser) to treat the datetime input from the user as datetime that needs to be converted from "Asia/Jerusalem" to UTC before saving to the DB since I performed `timezone.activate(pytz.timezone("Asia/Jerusalem"))`.

The same goes when the data is parsed back in the response through `JSONParser`.
While expecting DateTime fields in the returned JSON to be in the timezone activated in the middleware, they are returned as UTC.

How can I easily achieve that in DRF?

Comment: @yakxxx - Unfortunately not yet. For now I get and return datetime values in GMT and conversion to local timezone is done in the client's side.

Comment: Can you post a request? I wonder which format you used inside the JSON? Are you using a timezone aware ISO 8601 string?

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding new type of field:

```
class DateTimeTzAwareField(serializers.DateTimeField):

    def to_native(self, value):
        value = timezone.localtime(value)
        return super(DateTimeTzAwareField, self).to_native(value)
```

and now you can use it in `ModelSerializer`:

```
class XSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    start = DateTimeTzAwareField()
    end = DateTimeTzAwareField()

    class Meta:
        model = XModel
        fields = (
             'id',
             'start',
             'end',
        )
```

Comment: One small fix - if this field can also be null, a simple check is required, for example:

`if value: value = timezone.localtime(value)`

Comment: New Django-Rest-Framework, use `to_representation` instead of `to_native`

Answer (score 17):

The answer by @yakxxx seems to be the best solution.
I am posting it again after updating it to work with newer versions of restframework

inside my directory (common/serializers.py)

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.utils import timezone

class DateTimeFieldWihTZ(serializers.DateTimeField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = timezone.localtime(value)
        return super(DateTimeFieldWihTZ, self).to_representation(value)
```

Inside my application

```
from common.serializers import DateTimeFieldWihTZ

class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    start = DateTimeFieldWihTZ(format='%d %b %Y %I:%M %p')
    end = DateTimeFieldWihTZ(format='%d %b %Y %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: No need to check if value is None as suggested by  Ophir.
Apparently if value is none this method will never be called

Comment: Can I set `DEFAULT_DATETIME_PARSER='common.serializers. DateTimeFieldWihTZ' to change all the DatetimeField to DateTimeFieldWihTZ?

Comment: I am not aware of any rest framework setting with that name

Answer (score 4):

Since Django REST Framework v3.8.0(released in May, 2018), you don't need a custom DateTimeField any more.

In previous versions, Django REST Framework only convert native datetime to timezone aware datetime when parsing the date(`DateTimeField.to_internal_value()`), but do not convert when rendering the datatime field(`DateTimeField.to_representation()`). [This](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5408) is fixed in DRF v3.8.0.

You may need to change the following settings:

1. `USE_TZ` must be True
2. set `TIME_ZONE` to specify a default timezone
3. set `REST_FRAMEWORK.DATETIME_FORMAT` to the format that fits your frontend code.