# django rest framework timezone representation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django 1.9.6 and django rest framework 3.3.3 and I have a problem while representating datetimefield.

I use `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'` in settings.py. and

```
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my vpn(ubuntu) and postgresql timezone is set as Europe/Istanbul.

when creating or updating an object time is set as true on db tables. Datetime Representation is correct in django admin. but rest side is using UTC timezone.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-rest-framework timezone aware renderers/parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331578/django-rest-framework-timezone-aware-renderers-parsers)

Comment: @solarissmoke yes this solved my problem but auto_now=True is disabled.