# Django does not seem to account for DayLightSavings

Tags: django, django-timezone

In my models I want to update the `last_edited` value of the `Submission` object everytime the `UserAnwser` object is saved.

To this end I've written the following code

```
from django.utils import timezone
...

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
  answer = models.FloatField()
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
  submission = models.ForeignKey(AssessmentSubmission, related_name='answers')


  #Update submission.last_edited on answer.
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      submission = self.submission
      submission.last_edited = timezone.now
      submission.save()
      super(UserAnswer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've set the correct timezone in the `settings.py` file:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

However, everytime I change the answer and lookup the submission.last_edited value in our django-rest api, the time is 1 hour behind the actual time. Its almost as if the time is being displayed in 'summer time' and the DST is not handled correctly.
For example, if I edit an answer at `13:30`, our api will return `12:30`

Since the `settings.TIMEZONE` has been set and I am using django's django.utils timezone object it should all be working.

Especially since the Time that is shown in the admin is the correct one, so its going wrong somewhere within our API. Yet our serialiser isn't doing anything to exiting, so its not clear to me where it goes wrong.

```
class AssessmentSubmissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  comments = CommentedItemSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

  class Meta:
      model = am.AssessmentSubmission
      fields = ('user', 'submission_date', 'start_date', 'last_edited', 'shared_with', 'assessment', 'scores', 'user_answers', 'comments', )
```

could someone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: CEST would be +2 on UTC, you have been returned the UTC time without timezone adjustments. Check how entry is presented in your DB and show us relevant code that displays time.

Comment: The time in the admin / database is the correct time! It seems to be an issue with the Django-rest-framework, I've updated me question - thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

Thanks to iklinac's response I figured out that the problem was located within our Django-rest framework code.

I solved it by [following Ramast his instructions within this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331578/django-rest-framework-timezone-aware-renderers-parsers)